# How do I set the navigation item's title?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to set Navigation Item's title.

But I got an error message like below

Anyone know about this problem?

[image]

Here is my code

import UIKit

```
import Parse

var show = String()
var user = String()


class FansTableVC: UITableViewController {

    //Arrays to hold data received from servers
    var usernameArray = [String]()
    var profileImgArray = [PFFile]()

    // Array showing who do we follow or who followings us
    var myfansArray = [String]()

    //Array showing who do we follow or who following us
    var followingArray = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Title at the top
        self.navigationItem.title = show

        // New back button
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backBtn"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(FansTableVC.back(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-8, for: UIBarMetrics.default)

//        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdge.None;
//        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false;
//        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false


//        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44.0);
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);


        self.tableView!.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self.tableView!.estimatedRowHeight = 82.0 //needed for autolayout




        //load Fans
        if show == "Fans" {
            loadFans()
        }

        //load Followings
        if show == "Followings" {
            loadFollowings()
        }


    }
    //cell height
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

This code was working fine in Xcode 7. It just happened Xcode 8

Comment: please post all your code, because this code compiles flawlessly.

Comment: @Eric I'm sorry. I update my code

Comment: change the var name `show` to something else like `programTitle`... it looks like your `show` there is somehow autocompleting to `func show(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?)`.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann OMG.... I've solved!! Thank you so much. I'm really appreciate for you :D